iOS Programmatically get (*.ips) Crash Logs
When I plug my ipad into my macbook I can fetch the device crash logs (*.ips files) in Xcode from
/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeviceLogs/myipad

It seems I would be able to retrieve these same files from code on the iPad with the FileManager, but I don't know where they live.
I have looked around with the following:
let LogDirAttempt = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("../")
let fm = FileManager.default
do {
    let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: LogDirAttempt, includingPropertiesForKeys: .none)
    for item in items {
        print("Found \(item)")
    }
    } catch{
        print("ERROR")
}


You can get them from code with import MetricKit by on start initializing MetricKitManager(). I am able to post the crash reports to my server by handling the didReceive methods (see below). When I tested this the app had to be installed on my device for a little while (maybe an hour) before the Metric Kit became active and started receiving the crash reports as formatted base64 strings on launch of the app after the previous crash.
Note that crashes caught by xcode are not received by Metric Kit and crashes on the simulator are not received by Metric Kit, so you must launch from the app from your device and crash to test.
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
class MetricKitManager: NSObject, MXMetricManagerSubscriber {
    public override init() {
        super.init()
        
        let metricManager = MXMetricManager.shared
        metricManager.add(self)
    }
    
    func receiveReports() {
        let shared = MXMetricManager.shared
        shared.add(self)
    }
    
    func pauseReports() {
        let shared = MXMetricManager.shared
        shared.remove(self)
    }
    
    func didReceive(_ payloads: [MXMetricPayload]) {
        var attachments: [String] = []
        for payload in payloads {
            let attachment = payload.jsonRepresentation().base64EncodedString()
            attachments.append(attachment)
            SubmitFeedback(eid: Employee.eid ?? "", message: attachment)
        }
    }
    
    func didReceive(_ payloads: [MXDiagnosticPayload]) {
        var attachments: [String] = []
        for payload in payloads {
            let attachment = payload.jsonRepresentation().base64EncodedString()
            attachments.append(attachment)
            SubmitFeedback(eid: Employee.eid ?? "", message: attachment)
        }
        
    }
}

